# What does it means this error?" In template: call to deleted constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<InventoryElements>"

Tags: c++

this is the class with all the methods.

```
#include "InventoryElements.h"
class Inventory{
public:
    explicit Inventory(int max) : MaxElements(max){
        myInventory.resize(max);
        NumElements=0;
    }

    void suf_insert(unique_ptr<InventoryElements> element);
    void generic_insert(unique_ptr<InventoryElements> element, vector<  unique_ptr<InventoryElements>>::iterator pos);

    void remove(unique_ptr<InventoryElements> element,vector< unique_ptr<InventoryElements>>::iterator pos);

private:
    int MaxElements;
    vector<unique_ptr<InventoryElements>> myInventory;
    int NumElements;
};
void Inventory::suf_insert(std::unique_ptr<InventoryElements> element) {
    if (NumElements < MaxElements){
        myInventory.push_back(element); // here the error
        
    else
        std::cout<<"Ops.. your Inventory is full, remove an element first"<< endl;
}
```

and this is the implementation of the first method, a suf_insert, the error call to deleted constructor of 'std::unique_ptr",

how can i solve this?

Comment: `unique_ptr`s cannot be copied, if they could they were not unique

Comment: You will have to pass the unique_ptr to your element as const reference (to not copy it), and then move your it into the collection `myInventory.emplace_back(std::move(element));`  After the suf_insert call the original unique_ptr will no longer point to the element since you transfered ownership to the vector now.

Comment: @PepijnKramer _You will have to pass the unique_ptr to your element as const reference_ Sorry, no. (I believe this doesn't make things better.) If you pass the `std::unique_ptr` as const reference, then you cannot move it (as moving requires to change the origin). I think it has to be a _non-const_ reference or an RValue reference. Maybe, the non-const reference is even better to handle the case that the `suf_insert()` fails to insert. (With an RValue reference, I'm not sure how to prevent the leak of the `element` if it's not moved in case the inventory is ful.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I see what you mean. I didn't want to introduce r-value references in the example (and over simplified). The function will have to transfer ownership by design it would semantically be the most correct.  And then if the Inventory is full nothing will be moved and the caller is still the owner.

Comment: @PepijnKramer To be honest, my reasoning was partly wrong. It would work with either reference or RValue reference - no leak in either of them. [MCVE on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7278df359fb53560) (Actually, your reply made me re-thinking of that.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Well sometimes that's C++ too, even after 25 years of almost daily use. I mostly rely on experience to make my examples here not on rigorous application of all the rules in the standard. And like you I still can be (partly) wrong. In any case thanks for your link, the result eases my mind ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a `std::unique_ptr` can not be *copied*, you will need to **move** your unique_ptr into your vector.

```
    myInventory.push_back( std::move(element) ); // no more error
```

After this line, `element` will no longer point to your element, as your `std::vector` will now contain the unique pointer.